# how to display next and previous details from database on clicking next and previous buttons in servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

When I click next button the next data should be displayed.If I click previous button the previous data must be displayed from database using servlet.

This is my display.jsp

```
 <html>        
  <head>
    <script>
         function f()
         {
            rs.next();
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%   
       try
       {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/banquet", "root", "");
         Statement st=conn.createStatement();
         String query = "SELECT * FROM halldetails";
         st = conn.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery(query);
         rs=st.getResultSet() ;
         rs.next(); 
       } 
       catch(Exception e)
       {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
     %>  
    <form>
        <table cellspacing="20" cellpadding="25">
         <tr>
           <td>Name:<td>
           <td><%=rs.getString(1)%></td>
         </tr>
        </table> 
         <input type="button" value="NEXT" onclick="f()" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Only the first row details are displayed but when i click next button it is not displaying. Pls help by providing the code!!

Comment: How about using ajax ,you can send `id` of next row to display and then get result of that.

Comment: could u pls help me with the code!!I cant get u

Comment: You can use ajax , onclick of button you can passed value of next `id` to get display in your table .In your server code you will have a `query` to retreieve required row and `id` of next row as well , and you can passed both that data to your `current` page.